# I have created a method, but Java doesn't see it - Java

Tags: java

i have been learning programming for a while now from TheNewBoston and in the 80th tutorial hew was writing files. I followed his code word for word, but eclipse  says that the method is undefined for the the type "creatfile". I have checked over and over to see, but i can't see the problem. Here is the code.

creatfile.java

```
import java.util.Formatter;

public class creatfile {

private Formatter x;

public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Formatter("chinese.txt");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("you have an error");
    }

public void addRecords() { //there is an error on "void" and "addRecords"
    x.format("%s%s%s", "20 ", "Jacob ", " Peterson");
}
public void closeFile(){ //error here to
    x.close();
    }
  }
}
```

apple.java (my main class)

```
import java.util.*;

public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        creatfile g =  new creatfile() {
            g.openFile();
            g.addRecords();
            g.closeFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing a closing brace but your IDE is not informing you there is something wrong with your IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` method doesn't make sense. Try this:

```
public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        creatfile g =  new creatfile();
        g.openFile();
        g.addRecords();
        g.closeFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem in the main class. thanks. can you tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: @Petersoj There's no need for the curly braces unless it's a code block, which it's not in this case. Technically, though, the braces can't hurt; the real problem is that you didn't end the first statement with a semicolon.

Answer (score 5):

You missed a closing brace in the definition of `openFile()` {

```
public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Formatter("chinese.txt");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("you have an error");
        e.printStackTrace(); // <-- don't just say an error.
    }
} // <-- Add this.
```

Comment: that worked, but in my apples.java class i am still getting an error on the g.openFile();

Comment: What IDE are you using? @Petersoj. Your IDE should be telling you these things.

Comment: @Petersoj Add a stack trace! Don't just say an error...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i dont know which stack trace i should add. and besides i am a beginner. i will next time. thanks!

Comment: thanks that worked for the creatfile class!

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
creatfile g =  new creatfile() {
            g.openFile();
            g.addRecords();
            g.closeFile();
        }
```

to this:

```
creatfile g =  new creatfile();
g.openFile();
g.addRecords();
g.closeFile();
```